# Insert rows if not exist postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert a row into postgresql if not exist into table. My table structure is as below.

Table Name: test

id serial NOT NULL

unitid integer

eventid integer

date_time timestamp without time zone

I tried following query but gives me error near Select.

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (905, 10, '2015-09-23 13:34:26')
SELECT 905, 10, '2015-09-23 13:34:26'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM test
WHERE unitid = 905 AND eventid = 10 AND date_time = '2015-09-23 13:34:26'
);
```

Please any one give me good suggestion about it. I want faster way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying values and then you are including a selection. You need to write your `insert into` without `values`(...) and use the `select` you have there instead. Simple example

```
insert into items_ver
select * from items where item_id=2;
```

taken from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql). Try your selection first. Is

```
SELECT 905, 10, '2015-09-23 13:34:26'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM test
WHERE unitid = 905 AND eventid = 10 AND date_time = '2015-09-23 13:34:26'
);
```

If so, then you should have an insertion like this:

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT 905, 10, '2015-09-23 13:34:26'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM test
WHERE unitid = 905 AND eventid = 10 AND date_time = '2015-09-23 13:34:26'
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the best answer. Performance wise I have aroung 100,000 data and perform operation in around 22 ms. Thank you so much.